# Images barely showing up in Google Search rich snippets, is it a subdomain problem?

Tags: seo, subdomain, images, rich-snippets, structured-data

I have a recipe blog running WordPress with Yoast SEO. A problem I have is that in Google Search images are not showing up in all the rich snippets for my website. I would say they show in about 50% of the cases.

I recently starting running some tests and as it turns out that the Google Structured Data Testing Tool pulls all relevant info from my website which is submitted in the source code by Yoast SEO, including a relevant image. However, when I look at Google's Rich Snippet Preview, the relevant image doesn't show up in the preview (there is a placeholder saying "YOUR IMAGE").

Then I started thinking: I moved all my images to a subdomain (`media.example.com`) a few years back. If I look for specific posts in Google Image Search (like "Pizza margherita example.com"), usually only the images from my Instagram Feed in my sidebar show up. The coverage of images from my subdomain is low (but not non-existent). I have about 50 recipes times 3 images per recipe, but only about 20 show up (which are the same ones showing up in the rich snippets).

Bing does show rich snippets with images and all my images do show up in Bing's search.

Have a made a mistake by moving my images to a subdomain? Will the problem be fixed if I just submit my entire subdomain to Google for indexing? Or is my problem likely due to something else?

Comment: Images from subdomain are not really a problem (if using cdn - images are hosted externally aswell). How does your source code look like? Did you check all relevant pages manually, are the images properly named, all with alt text and all schema images visible within the code?

Comment: As @Alex says the subdomain should not be an issue. Do the images comply with size and format guidelines? If all is indeed valid, it may just be that Google is choosing not to show them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've since made some improvements to my websites. I've sped it up and also moved all of my images from media.domain to domain/media (which was easy, because the subdomain was for that folder anyway). Google has since started indexing all my images and showing rich snippets for most of my recipes within a few days. I believe there must have been an issue with the subdomain anyway or I was punished for having a slow website.